# why google app engine dynamic instances restart when there is heavy traffic

Tags: performance, google-app-engine

I am monitoring the google app engine, and found that when there is traffic about 10-20 concurrent users, and the memory of instance achieves a point of about 300M, the google app engine restart/re-initialise the instance itself! The point is it breaks the performance which leads to the very slow latency when the instance is restart, I am interesting on why GAE restart the app engine when there is traffic, I am running on dynamic instances(auto scaling). Hopefully anyone has the same experience can explain that.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/how-instances-are-managed

After adjust the config as per:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#health_checks

for java, put in appengine-web.xml:

```
<health-check>
    <enable-health-check>true</enable-health-check>
    <check-interval-sec>300</check-interval-sec>
    <timeout-sec>60</timeout-sec>
    <unhealthy-threshold>3</unhealthy-threshold>
    <healthy-threshold>1</healthy-threshold>
</health-check>
```

And this reduce the chance of instance restart when there are heavy concurrent user, origin setting is too easy to trigger the threshold and make the GAE restart the instances too frequently and avoid the performance which caused by restart of the instance.